# dropzonejs if else dz succes or error

Tags: javascript, php, dropzone.js

I have a problem with the dz success mark and dz error mark. I can't find how to display either one or the other that the result. I would like to do something like this:

```
if (success) {
    show dz-succes-mark
} else {
    show dz-error-mark
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here another suggestion:

```
Dropzone.options.dropzone = {
init: function 1() {
this.on("success", function(file) {alert ("successful uploaded"); });   

}
init: function 2() {
this.on("error", function(file) {alert ("error!"); });  

}
}
```

Comment: hi Bauer,
My problem is that when I have a file ok it shows both l one below the other and an error that the dzsucces mark https://jsfiddle.net/0qoejLo2/2/